# How to center column values in a table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

How can I center the column values in this code?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
    \hline
    Reconstruction strategy & aa          & bb( \%) \\ \hline
    Classic                 & 3342 voxels & 68 \%   \\ \hline
    VC                      & 4296 voxels & 87 \%   \\ \hline
    V m=7                   & 4745 voxels & 96 \%   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \newline\newline 
  \caption{title}\label{tab1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{ccc}`

Comment: If you use `c`, then you can't define / set a horizontal size limit for the column (such as `2.5cm` in OP's example). If you use `c`, lines won't be automatically wrapped inside the table cells.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef) [remark: the linked question is more general, but the answer there is better that it gets hyphenation and `\newline` correct]

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You have to load the package `array`, define a new column type with horizontal centering

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

and use this one (`P`) instead of `p`

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|P{2.5cm}|}
    \hline
    Reconstruction strategy & aa          & bb( \%) \\ \hline
    Classic                 & 3342 voxels & 68 \%   \\ \hline
    VC                      & 4296 voxels & 87 \%   \\ \hline
    V m=7                   & 4745 voxels & 96 \%   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \newline\newline
  \caption{title}\label{tab1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you also want vertical centering, use `m` instead of `p`:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|M{2.5cm}|M{2.5cm}|M{2.5cm}|}
    \hline
    Reconstruction strategy & aa          & bb( \%) \\ \hline
    Classic                 & 3342 voxels & 68 \%   \\ \hline
    VC                      & 4296 voxels & 87 \%   \\ \hline
    V m=7                   & 4745 voxels & 96 \%   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \newline\newline
  \caption{title}\label{tab1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was about to write `\centering` in each cell before I saw your answer. ´;)

Answer (score 25):

If the width of the columns is not predefined, the most simple solution is to use `c` instead of `p`:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 Reconstruction strategy & aa          & bb( \%) \\ \hline
 Classic                 & 3342 voxels & 68 \%   \\ \hline
 VC                      & 4296 voxels & 87 \%   \\ \hline
 V m=7                   & 4745 voxels & 96 \%   \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\newline\newline 
\caption{title}\label{tab1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What to do for vertical alignment when the width isn't defined?

Comment: @Ruchir I have the same problem... did you solve it?

Comment: @hellomynameisA if you want to play with vertical alignment, you've got solutions here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113026/101631

Answer (score 15):

A very simple solution seems to work!

use `tabular` and `p{...}` and add `\hfil` before cell text. it seems that the text become centered! as an example:

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}}
        \multirow{2}{*} {something in multirow} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{another in multicolumn} \\
        & \hfil$Q in kg/s$ & \hfil$Q in m^3/s$ \\
        \hline
        first & \hfil7.3 & \hfil inf \\
        second & \hfil3.2 & \hfil0.5 \\
        third & \hfil inf & \hfil0 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you sure that it is centered then? Could you maybe add a code example illustrating this?

Comment: While this works, the actual reason it works is that **`\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil` by default** so the additional hskip at the end of the paragraph compensate for the initial `\hfil`, in my opinion it's **not recommended** to rely on this behavior. ⟨`\parfillskip` is a TeX primitive, see TeXbook or TeX by Topic for explanation.⟩

Answer (score 3):

It’s easy peasy with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray): you can specify horizontal alignment, vertical alignmnet and column width at the same time in the powerful `Q` columns.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{|Q[c,2.5cm]|Q[c,2.5cm]|Q[c,2.5cm]|}
    \hline
    Reconstruction strategy & aa          & bb(\%) \\ \hline
    Classic                 & 3342 voxels & 68 \%   \\ \hline
    VC                      & 4296 voxels & 87 \%   \\ \hline
    Vm=7                   & 4745 voxels & 96 \%   \\ \hline
  \end{tblr}
  \newline\newline
  \caption{title}\label{tab1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me using only \hfil followed by the text works perfect

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Comparison table} \\
\hline
Features & \hfil TreeMind & \hfil Calm & \hfil Headspace \\
\hline
Breathing exercises & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark \\
Meditation courses & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark \\
User's Feedback & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark \\
Virtual trainer  & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark \\
Sleep stories & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark & \hfil \checkmark \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A *partial solution*. It can help when you want to center text everywhere **but** in the last column (!)

Just add `\centering` in the cell you want centered text

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
    \hline
    \centering Reconstruction strategy & \centering aa          &   bb( \%) 
    \\ \hline
    \centering Classic                 & \centering 3342 voxels &  68 \%   \\ \hline
    \centering VC                      & \centering 4296 voxels & 87 \%   \\ \hline
    \centering V m=7                   & \centering 4745 voxels & 96 \%   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \newline\newline 
  \caption{title}\label{tab1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: It would be nice, if somebody says how to solve the error message of `\centering` in the last column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want fixed width horizontal columns with horizontally centered, single line entries, youmay be interested in `array`'s `wc`   column type:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|wc{2.5cm}|wc{2.5cm}|}
    \hline
    Reconstruction strategy & aa          & bb( \%) \\ \hline
    Classic                 & 3342 voxels & 68 \%   \\ \hline
    VC                      & 4296 voxels & 87 \%   \\ \hline
    V m=7                   & 4745 voxels & 96 \%   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a phantom extra column as p{0cm} at the end of the table for using \centering trick in it.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{0cm}}
\hline \centering 1 &\centering 2 &\centering 3&\centering 4& \\ 
\hline \centering 5  &\centering 6&\centering 7 &\centering 8 &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: If you want to horizontally center all contents inside of a `p` type column, it is easier to use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}` instead of adding `\centering` to every single cell. (Needs the `array` package) If you want multiple of these columns in your table, you may want to consider defining your own column type using `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`. You can then use `C{5cm}` instead of `p{5cm}`. With both of these suggestions, an empty extra column at the end of the table is not needed.