# Is it possible to make the column the same width?

Tags: tables

Is it possible to make the columns the same width without it being to complicated?

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c|c@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Injection Pressure {[}bar{]}} & \textbf{Time {[}s{]}} \\ \hline
1.0                                   & 120                   \\
1.5                                   & 120                   \\
2.0                                   & 90                    \\
2.5                                   & 90                    \\
3.0                                   & 90                    \\
4.0                                   & 60                    \\
5.0                                   & 60                    \\
6.0                                   & 60                    \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Various injection pressures and time setting}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on your definition of "too complicated". You can simply specify the width of the columns with `p{5cm}`. Or if you want them to be centred:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}P{5cm}P{5cm}@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Injection Pressure [bar]} & \textbf{Time {[}s{]}} \\ \hline
1.0                                   & 120                   \\
1.5                                   & 120                   \\
2.0                                   & 90                    \\
2.5                                   & 90                    \\
3.0                                   & 90                    \\
4.0                                   & 60                    \\
5.0                                   & 60                    \\
6.0                                   & 60                    \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Various injection pressures and time setting}
\label{my-label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*(based on [How to center column values in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157389/how-to-center-column-values-in-a-table))*

Comment: @campa Tell this the OP :) In my opinion the label is at the correct place, but the caption should come before the table :)

Answer (score 4):

or by use of `tabularx` on "very complicated/sophisticated" way:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcxl[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C|}{\bfseries #1}}
 \newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C }{\bfseries #1}}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{S[table-format=1.1] | S[table-format=3.0] }
    \hline
\mcxl{Injection\par Pressure [bar]}
            & \mcx{Time\par [s]}    \\  \hline
1.0         & 120                   \\
1.5         & 120                   \\
2.0         & 90                    \\
2.5         & 90                    \\
3.0         & 90                    \\
4.0         & 60                    \\
5.0         & 60                    \\
6.0         & 60                    \\  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Various injection pressures and time setting}
\label{my-label}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using `siunitx` you simply can set the `S` column width. I also loaded `makecell` for the common formatting of columnheads. The `\thead` (and `\makecell`, not used here) commmand allows for line breaks in their contents:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=3cm}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
  \label{my-label}
  \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.1] | S[table-format=3.0] }
    \Xhline{1pt}
    {\thead{Injection \\ Pressure [bar]}} & {\thead{Time [s]}} \\
    \hline
    1.0 & 120 \\
    1.5 & 120 \\
    2.0 & 90 \\
    2.5 & 90 \\
    3.0 & 90 \\
    4.0 & 60 \\
    5.0 & 60 \\
    6.0 & 60 \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Various injection pressures and time setting}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]