# Center fixed length table texmaker

Tags: tables

How I can center column with specifying width in table? For example, in the next code:

```
\begin{table} [H]  \footnotesize

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}
\centering
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1\arrayrulewidth}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{Massas e percentuais das frações separadas pelo ES.}
\vspace{-0.3cm}

    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}}

    \hline 
    Velocidades separação (m/s) & Quantidade de partículas & Fração mássica ($g$) & \% massa & Partícula de maior comp. ($mm$) & Partícula de menor comp. ($mm$) \\ 

\hline 
0,504 & 8200 & 7,6 & 15\% & 0,5 \pm 0,004 & 0,28 \pm 0,003\\
0,710 & 2040 & 5,0 & 10\% & 2,6 \pm 0,1 & 0,90 \pm 0,06 \\
1,062 & 450 & 9,0 & 18\% & 6,2 \pm 0,5 & 1,75 \pm 0,21 \\
1,578 & 432 & 10,8 & 21\% & 7,0 \pm 0,4 & 1,78 \pm 0,64 \\
1,930 & 227 & 5,4 & 11\% & 11,7 \pm 1,1 & 2,98 \pm 0,37 \\
2,277 & 149 & 3,1 & 6\% & 14,5 \pm 1,5 & 4,05 \pm 0,51 \\
$>$ 2,277 & 98 & 9,8 & 19\% & 17,2 \pm 2,2 & 4,15 \pm 0,63 \\

\hline 
\end{tabular} 
%\begin{tablenotes}
%  \item[]{{nd: Não detectado}}
%\end{tablenotes}
%\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}` should do what you are searching for.

Comment: Related: [How to center column values in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157389/134144)

Comment: i would use `S` columns and their syntax defined in `siunitx`. and please extend your code snippet to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Off-topic: What are you trying to achieve with `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1\arrayrulewidth}`?

Comment: By "centering", do you actually mean how to make the table fit inside the available width of the text block?

Answer (score 2):

I think there's an overriding issue with your table: it's wider than the textblock. (Well, unless your textblock is unusually wide -- something you haven't told us much so far.)

I'd like to suggest that you switch to a `tabularx` environment and a centered version of that package's `X` column type for all 6 columns.

Oh, I don't think it's typographically correct to typeset scientific units in math mode; use upright roman letters instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\small % not necessary to employ "\footnotesize"

%%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} % do you really need this?

\caption{Massas e percentuais das frações separadas pelo ES.}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{6}{C} @{}}
\toprule
Velocidades separação (m/s) & Quantidade de partículas & Fração mássica\newline (g) & \% massa & Partícula de maior comp. (mm) & Partícula de menor comp. (mm) \\ 
\midrule    
0,504 & 8200 & 7,6 & 15\% & 0,5$\pm$0,004 &0,28$\pm$0,003\\
0,710 & 2040 & 5,0 & 10\% & 2,6$\pm$0,1 & 0,90$\pm$0,06  \\
1,062 & 450 & 9,0 & 18\% & 6,2$\pm$0,5 & 1,75$\pm$0,21   \\
1,578 & 432 & 10,8 & 21\% & 7,0$\pm$0,4 & 1,78$\pm$0,64  \\
1,930 & 227 & 5,4 & 11\% & 11,7$\pm$1,1 & 2,98$\pm$0,37  \\
2,277 & 149 & 3,1 & 6\% & 14,5$\pm$1,5 & 4,05$\pm$0,51   \\
$>$2,277 & 98 & 9,8 & 19\% & 17,2$\pm$2,2 & 4,15$\pm$0,63\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a combination of `siunitx`, `booktabs` and `makecell` one can achieve the following table. As [suggested by Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/441930/center-fixed-length-table-texmaker/441935?noredirect=1#comment1108543_441935), I have replaced the units in math mode by `siunitx`'s units.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table} 
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\centering
\caption{Massas e percentuais das frações separadas pelo ES.}
\label{ua}

\begin{tabular}{S[input-symbols = {>},table-format=>2.3]
                S[table-format=4]
                S[table-format=2.1]
                S[table-format=2]
                S[table-format=2.2,separate-uncertainty=true,table-figures-uncertainty=1]
                S[table-format=1.3,separate-uncertainty=true,table-figures-uncertainty=1]}

\toprule 
{\makecell[tc]{Velocidades \\ separação \\ (\si[per-mode=symbol]{\meter\per\second})}} & {\makecell[tc]{Quantidade \\ de partículas}} & {\makecell[tc]{Fração \\ mássica \\ (\si{\gram})}} & {\% massa} & {\makecell[tc]{Partícula  de \\ maior comp. \\ (\si{\milli\meter})}} & {\makecell[tc]{Partícula de \\ menor comp. \\ (\si{\milli\meter})}} 
\\ 
\midrule 
0,504 & 8200 & 7,6 & 15 & 0,5 \pm 0,004 & 0,28 \pm 0,003\\
0,710 & 2040 & 5,0 & 10 & 2,6 \pm 0,1 & 0,90 \pm 0,06 \\
1,062 & 450 & 9,0 & 18 & 6,2 \pm 0,5 & 1,75 \pm 0,21 \\
1,578 & 432 & 10,8 & 21 & 7,0 \pm 0,4 & 1,78 \pm 0,64 \\
1,930 & 227 & 5,4 & 11 & 11,7 \pm 1,1 & 2,98 \pm 0,37 \\
2,277 & 149 & 3,1 & 6 & 14,5 \pm 1,5 & 4,05 \pm 0,51 \\
>2,277 & 98 & 9,8 & 19 & 17,2 \pm 2,2 & 4,15 \pm 0,63 \\

\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think it's good (typographic) praxis to typeset scientific units -- cf. `mm` and `g` -- in math mode. Since you're showing how to use the `siunitx` package, may write `\si{g}`, `\si{\milli\meter}`, and `\si{\meter\per\second}`?

Answer (score 1):

a combination of [leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134144/leandriis) and [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) answers :-) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{\footnotesize#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}
\caption{Massas e percentuais das frações separadas pelo ES.}
\label{ua}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                S[input-symbols = {>},table-format=>2.3]
                S[table-format=4]
                S[table-format=2.1]
                S[table-format=2]
                S[table-format=2.2,separate-uncertainty=true,table-figures-uncertainty=1]
                S[table-format=1.3,separate-uncertainty=true,table-figures-uncertainty=1]
                            @{}}
    \toprule
\mcx{Velocidades separação (m/s)}
    &   \mcx{Quantidade de partículas}
        &   \mcx{Fração mássica ($g$)}
            &   \mcx{\% massa}
                &   \mcx{Partícula  de maior comp. (mm)}
                    &   \mcx{Partícula de menor comp. (mm)} \\
    \midrule
0,504   & 8200  & 7,6   & 15    & 0,5 \pm 0,004 & 0,28 \pm 0,003\\
0,710   & 2040  & 5,0   & 10    & 2,6 \pm 0,1   & 0,90 \pm 0,06 \\
1,062   & 450   & 9,0   & 18    & 6,2 \pm 0,5   & 1,75 \pm 0,21 \\
1,578   & 432   & 10,8  & 21    & 7,0 \pm 0,4   & 1,78 \pm 0,64 \\
1,930   & 227   & 5,4   & 11    & 11,7 \pm 1,1  & 2,98 \pm 0,37 \\
2,277   & 149   & 3,1   & 6     & 14,5 \pm 1,5  & 4,05 \pm 0,51 \\
>2,277  & 98    & 9,8   & 19    & 17,2 \pm 2,2  & 4,15 \pm 0,63 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]