# In a table how can I put the number in the middle of each column?

Tags: tables

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{1.1cm}||p{1.1cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{1.1cm}| |p{1.1cm}| |p{1.1cm}| |p{1.1cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{W1011daily}} \\
 \hline
\textbf{1}& \textbf{2}&\textbf{3}& \textbf{\dots \dots} & \textbf{150}& \textbf{\dots \dots} & \textbf{252}  \\
 \hline
 1000.182  &  996.4293 &993.6557 &   \dots \dots & 992.7738& \dots \dots & 987.8528 \\
 996.6344&   990.0872  & 990.881  & \dots \dots & 999.3244&  \dots \dots & 989.349\\
 990.2731 &  987.3196 & 988.7692&   \dots \dots & 1030.053&  \dots \dots & 961.9883\\
 \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots &   \vdots  & \vdots &  \vdots  & \vdots \\
1013.578 &1023.227& 1071.947 &   \dots \dots & 832.6109 &  \dots \dots & 1143.922\\
   \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots &   \vdots  & \vdots &  \vdots  & \vdots \\  
  734.5305 &821.8897 & 825.8748 &   \dots \dots &  947.0167 &  \dots \dots & 1356.77\\

 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: All numbers or just the column headers?

Comment: @samcarter the headline

Answer (score 5):

To centre the column headlines you can use `\makecell[c]{...}` or `\thead` from the `makecell` package

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{1.1cm}||p{1.1cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{1.1cm}| |p{1.1cm}| |p{1.1cm}| |p{1.1cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\thead{W1011daily}} \\
 \hline
\thead{1}& \thead{2}&\thead{3}& \thead{\dots \dots} & \thead{150}& \thead{\dots \dots} & \thead{252}  \\
 \hline
 1000.182  &  996.4293 &993.6557 &   \dots \dots & 992.7738& \dots \dots & 987.8528 \\
 996.6344&   990.0872  & 990.881  & \dots \dots & 999.3244&  \dots \dots & 989.349\\
 990.2731 &  987.3196 & 988.7692&   \dots \dots & 1030.053&  \dots \dots & 961.9883\\
 \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots &   \vdots  & \vdots &  \vdots  & \vdots \\
1013.578 &1023.227& 1071.947 &   \dots \dots & 832.6109 &  \dots \dots & 1143.922\\
   \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots &   \vdots  & \vdots &  \vdots  & \vdots \\  
  734.5305 &821.8897 & 825.8748 &   \dots \dots &  947.0167 &  \dots \dots & 1356.77\\

 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally I'd prefer a cleaner table without all the vertical lines and numbers aligned by their decimal marker:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
        @{}
        S[table-format=4.4]
        S[table-format=4.4]
        S[table-format=4.4]
        X
        S[table-format=4.4]
        X
        S[table-format=4.4]
        @{}
    }
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{W1011daily}}\\
        \midrule
        {\thead{1}} & {\thead{2}} & {\thead{3}}& {\dots} & {\thead{150}}& {\dots} & {\thead{252}}\\
        \midrule
         1000.182 & 996.4293 & 993.6557 & \dots & 992.7738 & \dots & 987.8528 \\
        996.6344&   990.0872  & 990.881  & \dots & 999.3244&  \dots & 989.349\\
        990.2731 &  987.3196 & 988.7692&   \dots & 1030.053&  \dots & 961.9883\\
        {\vdots}  & {\vdots} & {\vdots} &  & {\vdots} &  & {\vdots} \\
        1013.578 &1023.227& 1071.947 &   \dots & 832.6109 &  \dots & 1143.922\\
        {\vdots}  & {\vdots} & {\vdots} &   & {\vdots} &  & {\vdots} \\
        734.5305 &821.8897 & 825.8748 &   \dots &  947.0167 &  \dots & 1356.77\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe this answer has been addressed, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157389/how-to-center-column-values-in-a-table).

To keep it most similar to the math Latex that I know, I would use

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 Reconstruction strategy & aa          & bb( \%) \\ \hline
 Classic                 & 3342 voxels & 68 \%   \\ \hline
 VC                      & 4296 voxels & 87 \%   \\ \hline
 V m=7                   & 4745 voxels & 96 \%   \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\newline\newline 
\caption{title}\label{tab1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Credit to [sandoval31](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101631/sandoval31) for that snippet of code.