# Vertical lines will not connect completely

Tags: tables, booktabs

The vertical line between 8 and comment will are not completely connected top.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{No.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Date} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Performed Test} & \multirow{2}{*}{Comment}\\ 
& & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  &  \\\specialrule{.2em}{.1em}{.1em} 


\end{tabular}
\caption{Chronology of Performed Tests.}
\label{Tests}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Do know how I can specify each column width while keeping it in center form ? I have used p{3cm} for instance but the text in the column is right justified ?

Comment: Reagrding centered p type columns, please see [How to center column values in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157400/134144)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the non-zero value of `\aboverulesep` in `\specialrule`. Use this code (I simplified the preamble of your table) which sets it to 0:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{11}{c|}}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{No.} & \multirow{2}{*}{Date} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Performed Test} & \multirow{2}{*}{Comment}\\
& & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & \\\specialrule{0.2em}{0em}{.1em}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Chronology of Performed Tests.}
\label{Tests}
\end{table}
```

[image]