# Misplaced \omit.\multispan ->\omit@\multispan. I expect to see \omit only after tab marks or the \cr of an alignment

Tags: tables, beamer

I made this table that after compiling works properly but I got the message above: can anyone please help me in order to understand what is wrong?

```
\begin{tabular}{cp{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}}
    \bigskip
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\large\textbf{\underline{Model}}}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\large\textbf{\underline{Parameters}}}\\
    \medskip
    & $\mu$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\lambda_p$ & $\lambda_b$ \\ \hline
    \medskip
    \textbf{Poisson} & - & - & - & $2,66\times10^{-2}$ & - \\ \hline 
    \medskip
   \textbf{ Hawkes} & close to 0 & 3.53 & 3.97 & - & - \\ \hline
    \medskip
    \textbf{Branching} & - & - & - & - & $0,13\times10^{-2}$ \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: You can't use \bigskip before a \multicolumn.

Comment: Off-topic(ish), but if each parameter only corresponds to one row, it might be better to not have the table at all.  I feel like one of the main points of the table would be to allow you to compare different entries in the same column, and that isn't applicable if each column only has a single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

- your first row only has 1+4=5 columns, while your table has 6 columns
- instead of trying to add skips, I suggest to use `\addlinespace` from the `booktabs` package

Not strictly speaking a problem, but with `0,13` the spacing around the `,` will most likely be wrong. I suggest to have a look at the `siunitx` package

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{cp{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}}
%    \bigskip
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\large\textbf{\underline{Model}}}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\large\textbf{\underline{Parameters}}}\\
%    \medskip
    & $\mu$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\lambda_p$ & $\lambda_b$ \\ \hline
    \medskip
    \textbf{Poisson} & - & - & - & $2,66\times10^{-2}$ & - \\ \hline 
    \medskip
   \textbf{ Hawkes} & close to 0 & 3.53 & 3.97 & - & - \\ \hline
    \medskip
    \textbf{Branching} & - & - & - & - & $0,13\times10^{-2}$ \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, now it works properly. Last things: if I want to preserve this setting but putting the data centering with respect to the column, what should I do? I try to change something in cp{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm} but it doesn't work...

Comment: @AndreaMazzoran Not sure if I understand your comment correctly, but if you are looking for centred p columns, this answer will help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157400/36296

Comment: That was EXACTLY what I was looking for, thanks again, you are a master!

Comment: @AndreaMazzoran You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but `\medskip` does ***not*** do what you expect to.

Consider the simple example

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
\medskip
c & d \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
c & d \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

and its output

[image]

As you see, the vertical space is added *below* the second row, not between the first and second row.

You want, instead, to use `siunitx` and `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
 >{\bfseries}l
 S[table-format=1.2]
 S[table-format=1.2]
 S[table-format=1.2]
 S[table-format=1.2e-1]
 S[table-format=1.2e-1]
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Model}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Parameters}}\\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-6}
  & $\mu$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\lambda_p$ & $\lambda_b$ \\
\midrule
Poisson & {--} & {--} & {--} & 2,66e-2 & {--} \\
\midrule
Hawkes & {close to 0} & 3.53 & 3.97 & {--} & {--} \\
\midrule
Branching & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & 0,13e-2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{
 >{\bfseries}l
 S[table-format=1.2]
 S[table-format=1.2]
 S[table-format=1.2]
 S[table-format=1.2e-1]
 S[table-format=1.2e-1]
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Model}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Parameters}}\\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-6}
  & $\mu$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\lambda_p$ & $\lambda_b$ \\
\midrule
Poisson & {--} & {--} & {--} & 2,66e-2 & {--} \\
Hawkes & {close to 0} & 3.53 & 3.97 & {--} & {--} \\
Branching & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & 0,13e-2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer to avoid as many horizontal rules as I can, so I showed also the table without the unnecessary ones.

[image]

The second table, with some added vertical space and no boldface:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{
 l
 S[table-format=1.2]
 S[table-format=1.2]
 S[table-format=1.2]
 S[table-format=1.2e-1]
 S[table-format=1.2e-1]
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Parameters}\\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-6}
  & $\mu$ & $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\lambda_p$ & $\lambda_b$ \\
\midrule
Poisson & {--} & {--} & {--} & 2,66e-2 & {--} \\
\addlinespace
Hawkes & {close to 0} & 3.53 & 3.97 & {--} & {--} \\
\addlinespace
Branching & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & 0,13e-2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Removing boldface is good, the additional vertical space is not really important.

Comment: Thanks, this is far better looking than mine. Last thing: if I want my table to be a little be wider (i.e. more space between \mu \alpha \beta ecc.) without messing up all the centering what do I have to change in the second code?

Comment: @AndreaMazzoran Are you sure this doesn't hinder readability?