# Latex custom table with different border colors

Tags: tables

I wanted to write the code for this specific table in Latex (the image just above).
I want to define the width of the table borders, the color of the table borders and also the white space between the two cells. I also wanted the text to be horizontally and vertically centered.

[image]

I tried something like this :

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, graphicx}


\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,255,0}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,0,255}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\noindent
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \arrayrulecolor{green}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|}
        \hline
         \color{green} GREEN \\
         \hline
        \end{tabular}
    & 
        \arrayrulecolor{blue}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|}
        \hline
             \color{blue} BLUE \\
        \hline
            \end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

I edited my code, it works, but I have a warning that I can't suppress :
"You have used a \hline command in the wrong place, probably outside a table. If the \hline command is written inside a table, try including \ before it."

It seems that I can't change the border's color inside a table.

Comment: Is this always going to be the one-row-two-columns table? If yes, you might consider more convenient approaches: a mix of `\parbox` or `minipage` and `\fcolorbox` (of the `xcolor` package); `tikz`; or `tcolorbox` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't necessarily need a table for this. You could place two boxes horizontally next to each other with a white space of your size:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
{%
  \centering
  \setlength\fboxrule{1mm}   % Line width 
  \setlength\fboxsep{6pt}    % Padding       
  \fcolorbox{Green}{Green!5}{%  or white instead of the tint Green!5
    \parbox{4cm}{\centering\textcolor{Green}{GREEN}}}%
  \hspace{2em}%A
  \fcolorbox{Blue}{Blue!5}{%
    \parbox{4cm}{\centering\textcolor{Blue}{BLUE}}}
\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could use [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and have a few more options, for example rounded corners. However, you would need to learn `tikz`, which is a huge package with extra modules and might be a little scary at first.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand\boxtext{Sample sample sample sample sample sample sample}

\tikzset{
  box/.style = {
    draw,
    line width = 1mm,
    color=#1, fill=#1!5,
    align=center, text width=4cm, font=\normalfont,
    inner sep=6pt+1mm, outer sep=0pt,
    rounded corners,
  },
}


\begin{document}
{%
  \centering
  \tikz[node distance = 2em] {
    \node (G) [box=Green] {\boxtext};
    \node (B) [box=Blue, right=of G] {\boxtext};}
  \par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, you can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` for the small tabular in the second cell of your main tabular. The environment `{NiceTabular}` has its own key for the colors of the rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, graphicx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,255,0}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,0,255}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\noindent
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \arrayrulecolor{green}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|}
        \hline
         \color{green} GREEN \\
         \hline
        \end{tabular}
    & 
        \begin{NiceTabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|}[rules/color=blue]
        \hline
             \color{blue} BLUE \\
        \hline
        \end{NiceTabular}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, however it seems that sometimes the line height is too high. Moreover, it is annoying to have to compile several times.

Comment: `nicematrix` draws its lines by using Tikz (in fact PGF which is a sublayer of Tikz). In the PDF such lines have not the same structure as lines drawn by (raw) TeX. That's why the PDF viewers don't render those rules exactly in the same way (it's linked to the antialiasing techniques). If you use only rules of `nicematrix`, the output will be perfect and homogeneous. For rules drawn by `nicematrix` with PGF, you should use `\Hline` instead of `\hline` (but, in your case, I would use the key `hvlines` of `{NiceTabular}`).

Comment: Concerning the multiple compilations, there are tools (such as `latexmk`) which do the successive compilations for you (for instance, Overleaf uses `latexmk`, afaik).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution using hhline and colortbl.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline,colortbl}

%New column type so that text is centered
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%Custom colors if needed
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,255,0}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,0,255}


\begin{document}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt} % thickness of table lines
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}  % horizontal spacing

%create a new hline called myhline with the colors needed
\newcommand\myhline[1]{%
\hhline{%
>{\arrayrulecolor {green}}%
#1|-% solid green colored line
>{}%
#1|~%  no line
>{\arrayrulecolor{blue}}%
|-#1%  solid blue colored line
}}


% start array
\begin{tabular}{
 !{\color{green}\vrule width 2pt } % vertical line color, line width
 M{5cm}  % custom column type, column width
 !{\color{green}\vrule width 2pt} 
 M{1cm}
 !{\color{blue}\vrule width 2pt}
 M{5cm}
 !{\color{blue}\vrule width 2pt}
}


\myhline{}% Draw custom line
\color{green} GREEN& &\color{blue} BLUE\\
\myhline{}% Draw custom line
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Here is the result.
[image]

References:

[Colortbl manual/guide](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.pdf)

[Hhline manual/guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/hhline.pdf)

[How to center column values in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157389/how-to-center-column-values-in-a-table)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. However with your solution you can't specify custom color.

Comment: \definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,255,0}<br/>
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,0,255}<br/>

One can simply add these lines to the preample (your original example had them, so I thought you might be able to tweak this code to your liking). However, I will edit my answer to add them to my code.

Answer (score 2):

A `tabularray` solution is missing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c,m,5cm, fg=green]cQ[c,m,5cm, fg=blue]},
        hline{1-2}={1}{green, wd=1mm},
        vline{1-2}={green, wd=1mm},
        hline{1-2}={3}{blue, wd=1mm},
        vline{3-4}={blue, wd=1mm},
        rows={ht=1cm},stretch=0
        }
        GREEN && BLUE \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]