# How to horizontally center p type columns in tabular?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, columns, width

I have this latex code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{26}{p{0.1cm}|}}
\hline 
\multirow {2}{*}{Activities} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{June} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{July} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{August} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{September} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{October} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{November} \\\cline {2-27}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\\hline 
lorem & \cellcolor {blue!50} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
ipsumffffffffffff &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
dolor &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
sit &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
amet &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor {blue!50} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Which produces this table:

[image]

As you can see, the numbers 1-26 are not in the center and even overflow (starting with number 10 up to 26). I have already tried it with `\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.1cm}}` ([How to center column values in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157389/how-to-center-column-values-in-a-table)) but it didn't work.

This is the whole document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{titling} 

\title{Some title
}
\author{Max Mustermann}
\date{November 2022}
 
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%  the preset of fancyhdr 
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[L]{Some other title}
    \fancyhead[R]{\theauthor}
}
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 1em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1em%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1em}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{cmbright}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section*{Description}
\lipsum[1] \\

\begin{tabular}{|c|*{26}{p{0.1cm}|}}
\hline 
\multirow {2}{*}{Activities} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{June} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{July} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{August} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{September} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{October} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{November} \\\cline {2-27}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\\hline 
lorem & \cellcolor {blue!50} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
ipsumffffffffffff &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
dolor &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
sit &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
amet &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor {blue!50} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And this is the whole document:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In fact, also the text in the cells where only one digit is present is not centered and overflowing already, which is because the cells are too small. Note that there is some space to the left and the right of the text in each cell.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you extend your code into a small example we can compile please starting with your document class?

Comment: Just to understand the question better: why don't you use `c` columns?

Comment: @JamesT I did now.

Comment: @Rmano Because otherwise the table is too big for the page. Thtat's why I have to use p columns.

Comment: @Philipp that's unrelated, you can have very tight `c` columns; what you see is the intercolumn space which is the same anyway (it *seems* to go away because the cell content overflows). See Zarko's answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You not provide any information about page layout.
- Column width of 0.1cm is far to small for content of cells, consequently it is spill out of this space (and cant be centered).
- Table size is to huge, that can be fit in text block.
- Possible solution are:

  - use `geometry` package and define wide `\textwidth`
  - enable protrusions table out of text block, for example into outer margin border by use of the `changepage˛package
- In both cases I suggest to use the `array` package, `\small` font size, reduce column separation  and use column type `w{c}{<column width>}`.
- The case with use of `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{26}{w{c}{1em}|}}
    \hline
\multirow {2}{*}{Activities} 
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{June} 
        & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{July} 
            & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{August} 
                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{September} 
                    & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{October} 
                        & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{November}     \\
    \cline {2-27}
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\\hline
    lorem & \cellcolor {blue!50} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
    ipsumffffffffffff &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
    dolor &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
    sit &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
    amet &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor {blue!50} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show borders of text block)

- The case with use of `changepage` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-2\marginparwidth}
\begin{center}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{26}{w{c}{1em}|}}
    \hline
\multirow {2}{*}{Activities} 
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{June} 
        & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{July} 
            & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{August} 
                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{September} 
                    & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{October} 
                        & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{November}     \\
    \cline {2-27}
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\\hline
    lorem & \cellcolor {blue!50} 
             &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
    ipsumffffffffffff 
          &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
    dolor &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &              \\\hline
    sit   &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &                \\\hline
    amet  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor {blue!50} 
                                              &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
    \hline[![enter image description here][2]][2]
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first solution works like a charm, thanks!
Just one thing: I don't see the point of `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}`. It seems redundant as I can adjust everything with `{w{c}{1em}` (e.g. using 0.35em instead of 1em and removing the `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}` line).

The second solution is also nice (as also suggested by @pascal974), but I will use the first one.

Comment: Also the `\small` command helps

Comment: @Philipp, you should be aware, that MWE you provide about 20 hours after I write my answer. In this time all yo0ur document settings was unknown, so my settings was based on guessing and no one was to much. Of course, they are not only possible.  However, you can change them as you wish according to your knowing of your document and desired table design. BTW, also second solution works!

Comment: Ok I understand. Next time I will provide the whole document right away.

Answer (score 3):

We have `Overfull hbox 2.15 too wide` with p{0.1cm}.

I propose:

- \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt} (6pt by default)
- the packgage `changepage` to widen the margins for the table

The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin = 2cm,
            showframe,%<-- comment in the final version
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\verb|\the\tabcolsep| = \the\tabcolsep


\lipsum[1]

\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.2cm}{-1.2cm}
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{26}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1em}|}}
    \hline 
    \multirow {2}{*}{Activities} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{June} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{July} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{August} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{September} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{October} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{November} \\\cline {2-27}
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \\\hline 
    lorem & \cellcolor {blue!50} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
    ipsumffffffffffff &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
    dolor &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
    sit &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline 
    amet &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor {blue!50} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\\hline
    \end{tabular}      
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solution also worked