\centering does not work for a particular table but forcing individual cell >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm} does it
I have this code:
\documentclass[a4paper,man,floatsintext,12pt,donotrepeattitle]{apa7}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} %Paquete de diccionario en español
\usepackage{graphicx} %Paquete Habilita pegado de graficos
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[inkscapelatex=false]{svg} % Para incluir archivos SVG
\usepackage{mathptmx} %Habita formulas matematicas?
\usepackage{titlesec} %Paquete que habilita el formateado manual de niveles
\usepackage{parskip} % Añadir este paquete para ajustar el espaciado entre párrafos
\usepackage{csquotes} %Tiene algo que ver para las referencias
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex} %Paquete apa
\usepackage{tabularx} %Para mayor customizacion de tablas
\usepackage{booktabs} %Para mejorar aspecto de las tablas
\usepackage{multirow} %Para combinar filas
\usepackage{geometry} % Para ajustar los márgenes si es necesario
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdflscape} %Para cambiar la hoja a horizontal
\usepackage{tabularray} %Para mayor customizacion de tablas
\usepackage{caption} % Para cambiar el nombre de las tablas
\captionsetup[table]{name=Tabla} % Para cambiar el nombre de las tablas

\addbibresource{referencias.bib} %Database referencias bibliograficas

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %Niveles de numeracion de titulos
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} %Espaciado entre parrafos

% Redefinir el formato de subsubsección para que no esté en cursiva
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\title{}
\author{}
\affiliation{}
\shorttitle{}

    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    
    \caption{Tabla de operacionalización de variables}
    \fontsize{8.5}{6.5}\selectfont
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|p{3cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Título:} & \multicolumn{6}{|p{18.5cm}|}{Influencia de la forma geométrica, la distribución de rigidez y el peligro sísmico en la flexibilidad de diafragmas y variación del periodo en edificaciones de concreto armado sobre suelos rígidos en el Perú.} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{OPERACIONALIZACIÓN DE VARIABLES}} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Variables} & \textbf{Def. Conceptual} & \textbf{Def. Operacional} & \textbf{Dimensiones} & \textbf{Indicadores} & \textbf{Tipo de Variable} & \textbf{Escala de Medición} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Independiente}} \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}{3cm}{Forma geométrica} & \multirow{3}{3.5cm}{Dimensiones directas o derivadas de la forma geométrica general de las edificaciones de concreto armado} & \multirow{3}{3.5cm}{Dimensiones parametrizadas de edificaciones de concreto armado resumidos en una ficha técnica} & Relación de aspecto en planta & Factor de la longitud mayor sobre el menor del diafragma \newline $R_p = \frac{L}{B}$ & Cuantitativa Continua & De razón \\ \cline{4-7}
        & & & Relación de aspecto en altura & Factor de la altura total entre la longitud mayor del diafragma \newline $R_a = \frac{H}{L}$ & Cuantitativa Continua & De razón \\ \cline{4-7}
        & & & Cantidad de niveles & Cantidad de niveles \newline $N$ & Cuantitativa Discreta & De intervalos \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{3cm}{Distribución de rigidez} & \multirow{2}{3.5cm}{Ubicación de diferentes elementos de concreto armado verticales y horizontales que aporten rigidez ante un sismo} & \multirow{2}{3.5cm}{Tipos de sistema estructural y de losas resumidos en una ficha técnica, que serán codificados con algún valor numérico} & Rigidez de elementos verticales & Tipo de Sistema Estructural (Aporticado, dual/muros) \newline $\theta$ & Cualitativa codificada & Nominal \\ \cline{4-7}
        & & & Rigidez de elementos horizontales & Tipo de losa (Aligerado 1 dirección paralelo, Aligerado 1 dirección perpendicular, Aligerado 2 direcciones, Losa Maciza) \newline $\kappa$ & Cualitativa codificada & Nominal \\ \hline
        Peligro Sísmico & Valor de la intensidad de aceleración sísmica máxima para suelos rígidos en algún lugar determinado en el Perú & Factor de zona según el reglamento sísmico & Factor de Zona (Según norma sísmica) & Aceleración máxima horizontal con 10\% de excedencia en 50 años normalizado con la gravedad \newline $Z$ & Cuantitativa Discreta & De intervalos \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Dependiente}} \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{3cm}{Flexibilidad de diafragmas} & \multirow{2}{3.5cm}{Valoración cuantitativa del grado de deformabilidad en el plano de losas de concreto armado} & \multirow{2}{3.5cm}{Ecuación regresiva que estima el valor de la flexibilidad de diafragmas según diversos criterios} & Índice de flexibilidad según ASCE 7-16 & Máxima deformación en el plano del diafragma dividido con el valor promedio de la deformación relativa lateral \newline $\gamma_f = \frac{\delta_{MDD}}{\Delta_{ADVE}}$ & Cuantitativa Continua & De razón \\ \cline{4-7}
        & & & Índice de Flexibilidad según Ju1999 & Diferencia entre deformaciones flexibles y rígidas dividido con la deformación flexible \newline $R = \frac{\Delta_f - \Delta_r}{\Delta_f}$ & Cuantitativa Continua & De razón \\ \hline
        Variación del periodo & Porcentaje de variación del periodo fundamental de la estructura considerando diafragmas flexibles que si fueren diafragmas rígidos & Ecuación regresiva que estima el porcentaje de variación del periodo fundamental de la estructura si es que se considerara los diafragmas flexibles & Porcentaje de variación del periodo fundamental & Porcentaje de variación del periodo fundamental considerando la flexibilidad del diafragma a que si fuese un diafragma rígido \newline $f_T = \frac{T_f}{T_R} \times 100$ & Cuantitativa Continua & De razón \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    
    \label{table:operacionalizacion}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}

At compiling I expected the whole table to be centered because of \centering parameter but it doesnt work. Forcing a column to be centering does work (>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm})

How to get the text centered?
Bonus for getting my table more prettier
I did something similar in a spreadsheet and it looks a bit better, solutions should be likely similar to that

PS: I tried importing the table as svg, but had issues at scaling.

\centering centers the table itself on the page, not the text inside. To do that you need c columns (one line) or >{\centering\arraybackslash} for p columns. You can define a new column type to make it easier to type as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157389/how-to-center-column-values-in-a-table, which is more or less a duplicate of your question. However, I actually think the left-aligned columns look better than the centered version, maybe you can leave it as it is.

as Marijn says about centering, also unrelated, but  \fontsize{8.5}{6.5}\selectfont  means place letters that are 8.5pt tall on lines that are 6.5pt apart, that can not work.

For “prettier” tables avoid all vertical lines (and most horizontal lines). See, e.g., the booktabs manual (available in several languages) for more information about good looking and easy readable tables.

@Marijn you are right, /centering "center" the "object" in question, which in this case is a table and not the text, my misconception was because I saw examples with /centering paragraphs (block of text) which made think that way I did and get upset in the process.
Such a subtle difference, it is very interesting.

@DavidCarlisle I did \fontsize{8.5}{6.5}\selectfont because otherwise my table wouldn't fit in a landscape a4 paper. Not quite sure if that may cause some issues in this table

there are no circumstances where that is a reasonable setting. use \footnotesize which is 8pt on 9.5pt
