# Column title on the second line

Tags: tables, columns

I am building a table of results in which I would like to have the column titles made of one line (as the first and the last two) being in line with the second line of titles made of two lines.

I know I have not been clear so I'll put an example of wht I would like to obtain:

[image]

I want to have "Outcome", "Bandiwdth" and "N" being immediately above the line as they are in line with the second line of multiple line column titles.

My code is the following:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{RD Treatment Effects on Schooling}
\adjustbox{max width=\columnwidth}{
\begin{tabular}{lccccccc} \hline\hline \\[-1em]
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) &  &  \\[0.1em] \hline \\[-1em]
Outcome & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\centering Linear RD \\  $\hat{h}$ bandwidth} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\centering Quadratic RD \\ $\hat{h}$ bandwidth} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\centering Cubic RD \\ $\hat{h}$ bandwidth} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\centering Linear RD \\ $\hat{h}/2$ bandwidth} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\centering Linear RD \\ $2\hat{h}$ bandwidth} & Bandwidth & N \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
Years of schooling & 0.340* & 0.305 & 0.320 & 0.238 & -0.00418 & 26 & 3,716\\
& (0.183) & (0.289) & (0.306) & (0.229) & (0.126) \\[1.2ex]
Completed primary school & 0.0193* & 0.0321** & 0.00435 & 0.406* & -0.0605 & 43 & 6,023 \\
& (0.0115) & (0.0142) & (0.0206) & (0.232) & (0.117) \\[1.2ex]
Completed secondary school & 0.00864 & 0.00882 & -0.0219 & 0.410* & 0.0229 & 25 & 3,453\\
 & (0.0263) & (0.0355) & (0.0589) & (0.215) & (0.133) \\[1.2ex]
Completed higher education & -0.00269 & -0.0324* & -0.0408* & 0.336* & 0.0833 & 44 & 6,373  \\
 & (0.0116) & (0.0178) & (0.0240) & (0.190) & (0.108) \\[1.2ex]
Literacy & 0.0273 & 0.0417 & 0.0238 & 0.253 & -0.0613 & 36 & 5,149 \\
 & (0.0245) & (0.0369) & (0.0534) & (0.225) & (0.122) \\[1.2ex]
 \hline \hline \\[-1em]
\multicolumn{6}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
 \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a [centered p column (replace m in this link with p)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/124577)? Or maybe `tabularx` and its `X` column?

Comment: Yes, but if I use p I get all the column formatted, whereas I just need the title to be at the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to very strongly discourage you from using `\adjustbox` to make the tabular material "fit" inside the text block: doing so will very likely generate extremely small and well-nigh illegible characters inside the table. Put differently: Don't use `\adjustbox` unless you want to signal to your readers that you don't really care whether they'll even try to peruse the contents of the table.

Instead, I suggest you learn how to make use of the `tabularx` environment. In the following code, I combine a `tabularx` environment with the facilities of the `dcolumn` package so that the numeric data are aligned on their respective decimal markers. And, use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` macro to generate well-spaced horizontal lines.

Speaking for myself, I would not move the words "Outcome", "Bandwidth", and "N" down one line. However, if you feel that doing so is really necessary, simply insert the instruction `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{b{#1}}` after loading the `tabularx` package.

The following screenshot shows the table that incorporates the suggested modifications, followed by your original table code that uses `\adjustbox` to shoe-horn the material into the width of the textblock. I hope you will agree that the upper table is more readable. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,dcolumn,adjustbox}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of 'X' col. type
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,skip=.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry} % those are awfully narrow margins...

% two handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{\texttt{tabularx} table, \texttt{dcolumn} and \texttt{booktabs} packages}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{5}{d{2.5}} cc @{}} 
\toprule
 & \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} & \mc{(5)} \\
\addlinespace
% use the 'C' column type on the five headers to allow automatic line-breakiing
Outcome & \mC{Linear RD $\hat{h}$~b'width} 
        & \mC{Quadratic~RD $\hat{h}$~b'width} 
        & \mC{Cubic~RD $\hat{h}$~b'width} 
        & \mC{Linear~RD $\hat{h}/2$~b'width} 
        & \mC{Linear~RD $2\hat{h}$~b'width} 
        & Bandwidth & $N$ \\ 
\midrule
Years of schooling & 0.340^{*} & 0.305 & 0.320 & 0.238 & -0.00418 & 26 & 3,716\\
& (0.183) & (0.289) & (0.306) & (0.229) & (0.126) \\ \addlinespace
Completed primary school & 0.0193^{*} & 0.0321^{**} & 0.00435 & 0.406^{*} & -0.0605 & 43 & 6,023 \\
& (0.0115) & (0.0142) & (0.0206) & (0.232) & (0.117) \\ \addlinespace
Completed secondary school & 0.00864 & 0.00882 & -0.0219 & 0.410^{*} & 0.0229 & 25 & 3,453\\
 & (0.0263) & (0.0355) & (0.0589) & (0.215) & (0.133) \\ \addlinespace
Completed higher education & -0.00269 & -0.0324^{*} & -0.0408^{*} & 0.336^{*} & 0.0833 & 44 & 6,373  \\
 & (0.0116) & (0.0178) & (0.0240) & (0.190) & (0.108) \\ \addlinespace
Literacy & 0.0273 & 0.0417 & 0.0238 & 0.253 & -0.0613 & 36 & 5,149 \\
 & (0.0245) & (0.0369) & (0.0534) & (0.225) & (0.122) \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{6}{c}{ $^{***}\ p<0.01$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{*}\  p<0.1$} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

    \begin{table}[h]
    \caption{For comparison, the original form of the table}
    \adjustbox{max width=\columnwidth}{
    \begin{tabular}{l*{7}{c}} \hline\hline \\[-1em]
     & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) &  &  \\[0.1em] \hline \\[-1em]
    Outcome & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\centering Linear RD \\  $\hat{h}$ bandwidth} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\centering Quadratic RD \\ $\hat{h}$ bandwidth} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\centering Cubic RD \\ $\hat{h}$ bandwidth} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\centering Linear RD \\ $\hat{h}/2$ bandwidth} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3cm}}{\centering Linear RD \\ $2\hat{h}$ bandwidth} & Bandwidth & N \\ \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
    Years of schooling & 0.340* & 0.305 & 0.320 & 0.238 & -0.00418 & 26 & 3,716\\
    & (0.183) & (0.289) & (0.306) & (0.229) & (0.126) \\[1.2ex]
    Completed primary school & 0.0193* & 0.0321** & 0.00435 & 0.406* & -0.0605 & 43 & 6,023 \\
    & (0.0115) & (0.0142) & (0.0206) & (0.232) & (0.117) \\[1.2ex]
    Completed secondary school & 0.00864 & 0.00882 & -0.0219 & 0.410* & 0.0229 & 25 & 3,453\\
     & (0.0263) & (0.0355) & (0.0589) & (0.215) & (0.133) \\[1.2ex]
    Completed higher education & -0.00269 & -0.0324* & -0.0408* & 0.336* & 0.0833 & 44 & 6,373  \\
     & (0.0116) & (0.0178) & (0.0240) & (0.190) & (0.108) \\[1.2ex]
    Literacy & 0.0273 & 0.0417 & 0.0238 & 0.253 & -0.0613 & 36 & 5,149 \\
     & (0.0245) & (0.0369) & (0.0534) & (0.225) & (0.122) \\[1.2ex]
     \hline \hline \\[-1em]
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
     \end{tabular}}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily obtain what you want with the `\thead` command from `makecell`. I added some improvements to your table, using the `S` column type from `siunits` and `booktabs`. I removed the `\adjustbox` command, which should not normally be used with tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx, makecell, booktabs}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{cb}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!hb]
  \sisetup{table-format =-1.5, table-number-alignment =center, table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post =)**, table-align-text-pre=false, table-align-text-post=false}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \caption{RD Treatment Effects on Schooling}
  \small\centering
  \begin{tabular}{l*{5}{S}cc}
                               & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & & \\
    \addlinespace
    \toprule
    Outcome & {\thead{Linear RD \\ $\hat{h}$ bandwidth}} & {\thead{Quadratic RD \\ $\hat{h}$ bandwidth}} & {\thead{Cubic RD \\ $\hat{h}$ bandwidth}} & {\thead{Linear RD \\ $\hat{h}/2$ bandwidth}} & {\thead{Linear RD \\ $2\hat{h}$ bandwidth}} & Bandwidth & N \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace[2ex]
    Years of schooling & 0.340* & 0.305 & 0.320 & 0.238 & -0.00418 & 26 & 3,716 \\
    & {(}0.183{)} & {(}0.289{)} & {(}0.306{)} & {(}0.229{)} & {(}0.126{)} \\
    \addlinespace
    Completed primary school & 0.0193* & 0.0321** & 0.00435 & 0.406* & -0.0605 & 43 & 6,023 \\
    & {(}0.0115{)} & {(}0.0142{)} & {(}0.0206{)} & {(}0.232{)} & {(}0.117{)} \\
    \addlinespace
    Completed secondary school & 0.00864 & 0.00882 & -0.0219 & 0.410* & 0.0229 & 25 & 3,453 \\
    &{(}0.0263{)} & {(}0.0355{)} & {(}0.0589{)} & {(}0.215{)} & {(}0.133{)} \\
    \addlinespace
    Completed higher education & -0.00269 & -0.0324* & -0.0408* & 0.336* & 0.0833 & 44 & 6,373 \\
    & {(}0.0116{)} & {(}0.0178{)} & {(}0.0240{)} & {(}0.190{)} & {(}0.108{)} \\
    \addlinespace
    Literacy & 0.0273 & 0.0417 & 0.0238 & 0.253 & -0.0613 & 36 & 5,149 \\
    & {(}0.0245{)} & {(}0.0369{)} & {(}0.0534{)} & {(}0.225{)} & {(}0.122{)} \\
    \addlinespace
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `array` package and the `b` column type ([helpful link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113026/124577)).

[image: table and b]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{RD Treatment Effects on Schooling}
\adjustbox{max width=\columnwidth}{
\begin{tabular}{lccccccc} \hline\hline \\[-1em]
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) &  &  \\[0.1em] \hline \\[-1em]
Outcome & \multicolumn{1}{b{3cm}}{\centering Linear RD \\  $\hat{h}$ bandwidth} & \multicolumn{1}{b{3cm}}{\centering Quadratic RD \\ $\hat{h}$ bandwidth} & \multicolumn{1}{b{3cm}}{\centering Cubic RD \\ $\hat{h}$ bandwidth} & \multicolumn{1}{b{3cm}}{\centering Linear RD \\ $\hat{h}/2$ bandwidth} & \multicolumn{1}{b{3cm}}{\centering Linear RD \\ $2\hat{h}$ bandwidth} & Bandwidth & N \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
Years of schooling & 0.340* & 0.305 & 0.320 & 0.238 & -0.00418 & 26 & 3,716\\
& (0.183) & (0.289) & (0.306) & (0.229) & (0.126) \\[1.2ex]
Completed primary school & 0.0193* & 0.0321** & 0.00435 & 0.406* & -0.0605 & 43 & 6,023 \\
& (0.0115) & (0.0142) & (0.0206) & (0.232) & (0.117) \\[1.2ex]
Completed secondary school & 0.00864 & 0.00882 & -0.0219 & 0.410* & 0.0229 & 25 & 3,453\\
 & (0.0263) & (0.0355) & (0.0589) & (0.215) & (0.133) \\[1.2ex]
Completed higher education & -0.00269 & -0.0324* & -0.0408* & 0.336* & 0.0833 & 44 & 6,373  \\
 & (0.0116) & (0.0178) & (0.0240) & (0.190) & (0.108) \\[1.2ex]
Literacy & 0.0273 & 0.0417 & 0.0238 & 0.253 & -0.0613 & 36 & 5,149 \\
 & (0.0245) & (0.0369) & (0.0534) & (0.225) & (0.122) \\[1.2ex]
 \hline \hline \\[-1em]
\multicolumn{6}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
 \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```