# Vertical alignment of text in a column

Tags: vertical

I'd like to know how to center de text in the first column for this table:

```
\begin{figure}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{gray!30}} c}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[!htb]{|a|c|c|c|  }
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!50} 
F/B & 0 [T] & 1 [T] & 4 [T] \\
\toprule
0.03$\left[{\frac{kV}{cm}}\right]$
&\includegraphics[width=38mm]{Graficos/Tablas/Rt_10_F_3000_B_0.pdf}&\includegraphics[width=38mm]{Graficos/Tablas/Rt_10_F_3000_B_2.pdf} &
\includegraphics[width=38mm]{Graficos/Tablas/Rt_10_F_3000_B_4.pdf}\\
\hline \addlinespace[1pt]
...
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

The result is this:
[image: u.u]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113022/vertical-alignment-in-tabular-cells-with-variable-height

Comment: this question is not duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113022/vertical-alignment-in-tabular-cells-with-variable-height. however similar questions with images in tables, which has some specific and can be solved on different /more elegant ?/ ways as proposed in answers in link, has been asked many times.  Already *John Kormilo* answer gives better help than answers in links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to determine the height of the picture and use `\raisebox` to lift the text half way. The other is to use `\raisebox` on every picture to center the baseline.

For graphics, `\raisebox` is better than `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlength{\tempdima}

\newcommand{\vcgraphics}[1]% #1 = filename
{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=38mm]{#1}}}

\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{gray!30}} c}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\settoheight{\tempdima}{\includegraphics[width=38mm]{example-image}}% get image height
\centering
\begin{tabular}[!htb]{|a|c|c|c|  }
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!50} 
F/B & 0 [T] & 1 [T] & 4 [T] \\
\toprule
\raisebox{0.5\tempdima}{0.03$\left[{\frac{kV}{cm}}\right]$}
&\includegraphics[width=38mm]{example-image-a}&\includegraphics[width=38mm]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[width=38mm]{example-image-c}\\
\hline \addlinespace[1pt]
0.03$\left[{\frac{kV}{cm}}\right]$
&\vcgraphics{example-image-a}&\vcgraphics{example-image-b} &
\vcgraphics{example-image-c}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you, that works very well !!! <3 :3  I tried the answers for others post but those didn't work for me.