# Cells vertical alignment when a row title is vertical

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rotating

consider the following table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|cc}
\cmidrule{2-3}
 & \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2}\\
\midrule
\begin{sideways} \textbf{Row 1} \end{sideways} & \multirow{2}{*}{Text row 1 - 2} & Text row 1\\
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}
\begin{sideways} \textbf{Row 2} \end{sideways} &  & Text row 2\\
\midrule
\begin{sideways} \textbf{Row 3} \end{sideways} & Text row 3 & Text row 3\\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

How can I centralize the row texts vertically?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this anwser : [Vertical alignment in tabular cells with variable height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113022/vertical-alignment-in-tabular-cells-with-variable-height)

And adjusting with `bigstruts` argument of `multirow`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|cc}
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    & \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2}\\
    \midrule
    \noindent\parbox[c]{12pt}{\begin{sideways} \textbf{Row 1} \end{sideways}} & \multirow{2}[12]{*}{Text row 1 - 2} & Text row 1\\
    \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{3-3}
    \noindent\parbox[c]{12pt}{\begin{sideways} \textbf{Row 2} \end{sideways}} &  & Text row 2\\
    \midrule
    \noindent\parbox[c]{12pt}{\begin{sideways} \textbf{Row 3} \end{sideways}} & Text row 3 & Text row 3\\
    \midrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]