# Text vertical alignment inside cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I found few question about this but I cannot get it work. I want that everything inside my table is centred vertically and horizontally.

```
\begin{table}[h!]\centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \hline
        & LH                    & RH                    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Adjust Phase}              &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{TE11-TE21}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{figure/te1121_lh}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{figure/te1121_rh}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{figure/te1121_corr}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$e^{-j90^\circ}$} &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{HE11-HE21}      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{TE11-TM01/TE01} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{HE11-TM01/TE01} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\end{table}
```

An answer here said that `m` inside `multicolumn` does the work, but when I try to replace `\multicolumn{1}{l|}` with `\multicolumn{1}{m|}` gives me multiple errors. What can I do?

Comment: The `m` column specifier (as well as `p` or `b`) is for columns in paragraph mode, ans it requires an argument – the column width.

Comment: Here  [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113022/vertical-alignment-in-tabular-cells-with-variable-height] used `\multicolumn{1}{|m{\tempwidth}|}` but give me error as well

Comment: If you want everything to be vertically and **horizontally** centered, why do you use `\multicolumn{1}{l|}`  commands? Also, why do you specify 6 columns, as you only seem to use 5 of them?

Comment: For further information on the alignment of images, you might also want to have a look here:  [How to vertically center text with an image in the same row of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19080/134144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with use of the macro `valign=c` from the package `adjustbox` and with some effort to make table code shoerter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\makegapedcells
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
 \begin{tabular}{l|*{3}{p{0.15\textwidth}|}c}
    \hline
            & LH        & RH                & Adjust Phase      &   \\
        \hline
TE11-TE21   & \includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image}    & \includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image}
            & \includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image}       & $e^{-j90^\circ}$  \\  \hline
HE11-HE21       &       &                   &                   &                   \\  \hline
TE11-TM01/TE01  &       &                   &                   &                   \\  \hline
HE11-TM01/TE01  &       &                   &                   &                   \\  \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

if you rely kike to have contents in all cells horizontally centered, than define table columns as

```
\begin{tabular}{c|*{3}{p{0.15\textwidth}|}c} % in first column use "c" instead "l"
```

than you will obtain:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain what you want with a `\raisebox{-0.5\height}` (approximately):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|*{4}{c|}c}
        \hline
        & LH & RH & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Adjust Phase} & \\ \hline
         TE11-TE21 & \raisebox{-0.46\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{femme-araignee}}& \raisebox{-0.46\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{femme-araignee}} & \raisebox{-0.46\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{snark}} & $e^{-j90^\circ}$ & \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{HE11-HE21} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{TE11-TM01/TE01} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{HE11-TM01/TE01} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using some external utility for making the table, which would explain the wealth of useless `\multicolumn` commands.

Here are two forms for your table, one jailed and one without vertical rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for the better table

\newcommand{\vcincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \includegraphics[#1,valign=c]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  & LH
  & RH
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Adjust Phase} \\
\hline
TE11-TE21
  & \vcincludegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image}
  & \vcincludegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image}
  & \vcincludegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image}
  & $e^{-j90^\circ}$ \\
\hline
HE11-HE21      & & & & \\
\hline
TE11-TM01/TE01 & & & & \\
\hline
HE11-TM01/TE01 & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
  & LH
  & RH
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Adjust Phase} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}
TE11-TE21
  & \vcincludegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image}
  & \vcincludegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image}
  & \vcincludegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image}
  & $e^{-j90^\circ}$ \\
\addlinespace
HE11-HE21
  & \vcincludegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image}
  & \vcincludegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image}
  & \vcincludegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image}
  & $e^{-j90^\circ}$ \\
TE11-TM01/TE01 & & & & \\
HE11-TM01/TE01 & & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{My caption for the better table}
\label{my-label-better}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]