# How to center text in tabular vertically

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I wrote a table with `tabular` in LaTeX and I would like to center a column vertically.

Here is the code that I have :

```
\documentclass{11pt}{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

% to choose length and the left/right/center text
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{tabular}{|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{6cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|}
\hline
$I$ & $J$ & $\textrm{Représentation graphique}$ & $I\cap J$ & $I \cup J$ \\
\hline
$]-4;5]$ & $[0;6[$ & \psset{xunit=0.4cm, yunit=0cm, yAxis=false}    %scales the picture, removes the y-axis
\begin{pspicture}(-5,0)(7,0)    
\psaxes[Dx=2, subticks=0]{->}(0,0)(-5,0)(7,0)   %creates axes
\psline[linewidth=1pt, linecolor=red]{]-]}(-4,0)(5,0)
\psline[linewidth=1pt, linecolor=blue]{[-[}(0,0)(6,0)
\end{pspicture}  & $[0;5]$ & $]-4;6[$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: what I obtain]

But my intervals go over the lines, and I remarked that in fact the text is not centered vertically.

How could I fix this? I mean, I don't want to create huge lines to solve my problem.

Comment: Try tabularray it has some complicated (although slow) logic that mostly works https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610971/250119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) The table, as it is, overflows the width of the text. It's easy to fix using the `tabularx` package which calculates the width of the selected columns to fit the table to the width of the text.

(2) The  `pspicture` can be shift using the optional `[shift=<number>]`.

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program =xelatex 
    
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
    
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}

\usepackage{tabularx}% added <<<<<<<<<
\newcolumntype{W}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % added <<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show the magins <<<<<<<<<
\begin{document}    
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}   

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|W|W|C{6cm}|W|W|}
\hline
$I$ & $J$ & Représentation graphique & $I\cap J$ & $I \cup J$ \\
\hline
$]-4;5]$ & $[0;6[$ & \psset{xunit=0.4cm, yunit=0cm, yAxis=false}    %scales the picture, removes the y-axis
\begin{pspicture}[shift=0.3](-5,0)(7,0)    
    \psaxes[Dx=2, subticks=0]{->}(0,0)(-5,0)(7,0)   %creates axes
    \psline[linewidth=1pt, linecolor=red]{]-]}(-4,0)(5,0)
    \psline[linewidth=1pt, linecolor=blue]{[-[}(0,0)(6,0)
\end{pspicture}  & $[0;5]$ & $]-4;6[$ \\[0.7ex]% increase the height of the row
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```