# Vertical and horizontal centering of tabularx X cells

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
\begin{tabularx}{418.26pt}{|c|c|c|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{black!20}Nr. & Date & Version & Changed Chapters & Types of Change & Autor & Status\\\hline
1 & 06.12.2022 & 0.1 & Alle & First Draft & Long Ass Lastname & -\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

which results in the following output

[image: screenshot of output]

In addition to centering the cells horizontally, I also want to center them vertically. Ideally, I'd like to define a variant of the cell type X so as to not clutter the actual contents of the table with special case handling.

---

I've tried both solutions involving `tabularx` proposed at [Vertical alignment in tabular cells with variable height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113022/vertical-alignment-in-tabular-cells-with-variable-height), but neither worked satisfactorally.

The `\parbox` solution

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
\begin{tabularx}{418.26pt}{|c|c|c|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{black!20}Nr. & Date & Version & \noindent\parbox[c]{\hsize}{Changed Chapters} & \noindent\parbox[c]{\hsize}{Types of Change} & Autor & Status\\\hline
1 & 06.12.2022 & 0.1 & Alle & First Draft & \noindent\parbox[c]{\hsize}{Long Ass Lastname} & -\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

results in this monstrosity

[image: vertical size of multiline cells shrinks and word spacing spazzes out]

The `\multicolumn` "solution" is just as bad (except also having to guess an appropriate cell width)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
\begin{tabularx}{418.26pt}{|c|c|c|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{black!20}Nr. & Date & Version & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{Changed Chapters} & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{Types of Change} & Autor & Status\\\hline
1 & 06.12.2022 & 0.1 & Alle & First Draft & \multicolumn{1}{|m{2cm}|}{Long Ass Lastname} & -\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: horizontal centering is off and the cell color in the first row doesn't fill the entire cell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works perfectly

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
{\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}%
\begin{tabularx}{418.26pt}{|c|c|c|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{black!20}Nr. & Date & Version & Changed Chapters & Types of Change & Autor & Status\\\hline
1 & 06.12.2022 & 0.1 & Alle & First Draft & Long Ass Lastname & -\\\hline
\end{tabularx}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: using `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}` is what is documented in the `tabularx`  doc

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to `arraystretch`, you might want to use struts. These are invisible elements which artificially extend height. On the other hand, `\arraystretch` is asymmetric and larger values make table look awkward; this can still be compensated by setting negative values to `\extrarowheight` (it requires `array` package).

The code below demonstrates using a custom strut. The macro `\mystrut[top][bottom]` adds invisible bars: top and bottom gaps, respectively. Then, this macro can be a part of a column definition affecting each row in the table.

Also, in narrow environments such as small cells, consider using `ragged2e` as well as `microtype`. The former provides improved macros to format paragraphs, such as `\Centering` or `\RaggedRight` among others, which in this example substitute `\centering` or `\raggedright`.

The code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e,microtype}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\NewDocumentCommand\mystrut{O{1}O{#1}}{%
    \sbox0{X}%
    \rule[\ht0]{0pt}{#1\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip}%
    \rule[#2\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip]{0pt}{#2\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}%


\begin{document}

%%% Struts added manually per row
\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|
        *3{c|}
        *3{>{\Centering}X|}
        *2{c|}
    }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{black!20}
    \mystrut%
    Nr. & Date & Version & Changed Chapters & Types of Change & Autor & Status \\
    \hline
    \mystrut 1 & 06.12.2022 & 0.1 & Alle & First Draft & Long Ass Lastname & - \\
    \hline
    \mystrut[1][2]%
    1 & 06.12.2022 & 0.1 & Alle & First Draft & Long Ass Lastname & - \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

%%% Struts added in column definition
\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|
        >{\mystrut[1.25]{}}c|
        *2{c|}
        *3{>{\Centering}X|}
        *2{c|}
    }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{black!20}
    Nr. & Date & Version & Changed Chapters & Types of Change & Autor & Status \\
    \hline
    1 & 06.12.2022 & 0.1 & Alle & First Draft & Long Ass Lastname & - \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}%
\end{document}
```

[image]